# TranslateBehavior does not take default fields on default locale

Tags: internationalization, cakephp-3.0, behavior

I'm using CakePHP 3.4, and I'm using it for a dual language website, where spanish (`es`) is the default locale. I have a `MangasTable` that implemented the `TranslateBehavior` for the field `slug` and I'm trying to querying it, which is as follows:

```
$manga = $this->Mangas->find()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'nombre'
    ])
    ->where([$this->Mangas->translationField('slug') => $slug])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

The point is, the part `$this->Mangas->translationField('slug')` will get me the translation-aliased field for the slug. More or less, `Mangas_slug_translation.content`. That's fine when it's localized as english, but with the default spanish, as there isn't any entry in the `i18n` table for this language, it returns me nothing. The poorman's approach would be having a condition for the language and assigning it to a `$field` variable, but that would not look very good.

Is there any other approach, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> The poorman's approach would be having a condition for the language and assigning it to a `$field` variable, but that would not look very good.

I'm afraid that's kind of what you have to do, given that the original fields are being replaced after the data has been retrieved, and that there is no functionality in the translate behavior that would figure the proper field for filtering. You can hide the logic somewhere in the model layer (the table, a custom/extended behavior) for DRYness, but generally there's no way around it AFAICT.

You may want to [**open an issue**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) and suggest an enhancement. Maybe an additional method that returns the proper filtering field depending on the current locale could complement the `translationField()` method.